# Get attribute from android theme not applied

Tags: java, android, android-styles

I am trying to read the attributes of a theme programmatically. but I do not wish to apply the theme to my activity.

Other questions/answers I have seen talk about reading the colour of the current theme.

My main purpose is to read the text colour of 
`android.R.style.Theme_Material` and `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light` but not limited to this, I will need to reach into Holo too, and also not just text colour but the colour/size/padding/etc of other attributes too.

As I said, I wish to do this programmatically and not through the styles.xml.

Most answers I found refer to

```java
getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { android.R.attr.textColor });
```

but as you can see, the very first part of this is the problem. This is for the current theme, not for an arbitrary theme.

I've tried to generate the theme myself, but as far as I get is

```
int res = android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light;
getResources().newTheme().applyStyle(res, true);
```

But this does not seem to work since the `mTheme` on the inside of the new theme is based on

```
Resources.this.mAssets
```

and I am afraid this is where my knowledge of being able to follow the android framework breaks down. Any help would be grateful.